# Silverlight c# adding tooltip to textblock

Tags: silverlight

I am generating a textblock in c# and want to add a tooptip to it which displays an image and some text. how can I do this without XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like this:-

```
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "Hello World";
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(txt, "Some Content");
```

Note that you can replace "Some Content" with any `UIElement` containing pretty much any content you wish.